# \newabbreviation: How to set a different short-form only in the first usage?

Tags: glossaries-extra

I would like to use a different short-form only in the very first usage of a `\gls` command. For instance, consider the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle{short-long}
\newabbreviation{cots}{COTS}{COTS, do inglês, \textit{Commercial Off-the-Shelf}}

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{cots}

Second use: \gls{cots}.
\end{document}
```

This results is
[image]

I would like to have something like this:
[image]

Thank you in advance.

PS: It is important that the short-form remains "COTS" because it should appear that way in the list of abbreviations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: B]

With this code.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\setabbreviationstyle{short-long}

\usepackage[nopostdot,nogroupskip,nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}

%\newabbreviation{cots}{COTS}{COTS, do inglês, \textit{Commercial Off-the-Shelf}}

\newglossaryentry{cots}{
    name={COTS},
    description={do inglês, \textit{Commercial Off-the-Shelf}},
    first={componentes de prateleira (COTS, do inglês, \textit{Commercial Off-the-Shelf})},
    text={COTS},
}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
    First use: \gls{cots}
    
    Second use: \gls{cots}. 
    
    \glsaddall
    
    \printglossary  
\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you very much for your posting!